# How to top align the text in UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to top align the text in tableView cell.I created a cell subclass and added the following in layout subview.However it doesn't work.What am I missing?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   CGRect newFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
   newFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMinY (self.contentView.bounds);
   [self.textLabel setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is putting the `UILabel` at high place in the cell, but the labels `height` might still be big, and as a result the text is not at the top.

Vertical align in `UILabel` is a problem. By default a text in `UILabel` is center vertical aligned. If you  want to see the text at the top you will have to change the label height to fit the size:

```
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
// Will keep the same X and Y so label will look like it moved
// to the upper left corner of it's frame.
```